# How to start debugger with FlashDevelop?

Tags: flash, flashdevelop

I am trying to debug my AS3 project, I get this status message:

> Waiting for Flash Player to connect to debugger

But, then, nothing happen, it seems the flash player cannot connect to debugger ?
Here is my settings:

FlashViewer: 
External Flash Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\FlashDevelop\Tools\flexlibs\runtimes\player\11.1\win\FlashPlayerDebugger.exe

FlashDebugger: Source Paths is empty.

I am using FlashDevelop 4.01 RTM, Flex 4.5 SDK

Can some one help please! I am using Flash debugger Player 11.1, Windows 7
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I found is to click debug button, then play button! the debugger will catch on ..

Answer (score 0):

Try 1 more step:

right click project’s name, select Properties ->
Output ->
Test Project, select Player: External Player

Comment: thanks, but its already set so, the solution I found is to click debug button, then play button! the debugger will catch on ..

Answer (score 0):

It's not a fault of flash develop, it's a fault of windows and an incorrect association + it's unwillingness to let you switch defaults for swf launching.

Solution:
Just download the latest debuggers, particularly the Projector Content Debugger, from this location http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html

Once you have it downloaded, in flash develop go to tools>program setting>FlashViewer and set the external path to the location of your file.

Exit flash develop, to be sure the settings are saved, and then open it up again to use it as you please.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem when installing FlashDevelop on a new PC, and the cause of this error was because I did not have a system-level file association for .swf files yet. I simply went to my output file, chose open with.., navigated to the location of the debug player, and then the debugger properly started when I ran the game from FlashDevelop.